# 2 checks tables Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Need to check for the status 0 or if there is no record in the table.

But only returns me error.

Where I am going wrong?

My Code:

```
SELECT session_id
FROM t_table_1
WHERE session_id NOT IN (select distinct session_id from t_table_2) 
OR (select distinct session_id from t_table_2 where status = '0')
```

I want the result  show me the session that does not exist and  status equal 0

Comment: add session_id not in again before the next subquery

Comment: combine the two subqueries using union.. the or is looking for a boolean expression not a continuation of the in clause..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT session_id
FROM t_table_1
WHERE session_id NOT IN (select distinct session_id from t_table_2) 
OR session_id NOT IN (select distinct session_id from t_table_2 where status = '0')`

OR

`SELECT session_id
FROM t_table_1
WHERE session_id NOT IN ((select distinct session_id from t_table_2) union 
 (select distinct session_id from t_table_2 where status = '0'))`

Both the above queries should work

Comment: Exist session_id check in status = '0', OR session_id EXISTS (select distinct session_id from t_table_2 where status = '0'), not working.

Comment: use not in only instead of exists and try. It is working with sample data

Comment: I want the result  show me the session that does not exist and  status equal 0

Answer (score 0):

Why you use two subquery when  you can get same result ?

using single sub query 
for E.g

```
SELECT session_id
FROM t_table_1
WHERE session_id NOT IN (select distinct session_id from t_table_2)
```

because you are using NOT IN when  your first Sub query return all rows of table

```
select distinct session_id from t_table_2
```

Comment: I want the result  show me the session that does not exist and  status equal 0

Comment: @lemon13 yes  I am trying to explain same thing that you not need to use two condition .. 
in comment you said that  you want record that session not exists .. then ..

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

- Use `not exists` rather than `not in`.  If there is a `NULL` value in the subquery, then `not in` does not behave intuitively.
- No need for `select distinct` in the subquery.
- Don't put a bare subquery in the `where` clause.   Use `exists`.

Hence:

```
SELECT t.session_id
FROM t_table_1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from t_table_2 t2 where t2.session_id = t.session_id) OR
      NOT EXISTS (select 1 from t_table_2 where status = '0');
```

I am not sure if this is exactly the logic your specify in the text (which is a bit vague).  Sample data and desired results are a big help in clarifying questions.

Comment: I want the result  show me the session that does not exist and  status equal 0